# Are there keybboard drivers for a compaq kb-9963 keyboard?

Tags: 12.04

I am running 12.04 x64 and got a keyboard. I recieved a Compaq KB-9963 keyboard from my teacher today. I looked for the Windows drivers but could only find them for Windows XP, so not recent drivers. Are there drivers available for this keyboard that will let me utilize the shortcut keys on there?

Comment: Have you tried using the keyboard without any specific drivers?

Comment: Yes, and while it works as a generic keyboard, the shortcut keys are the reason I want the right drivers for it. If they can be found, I want them for both Ubuntu and Windows 7, but If not I am prepared to use it as a normal keyboard as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you you're still looking for a Windows 7 driver, you can find it [here](http://www.cryingbyte.de/verschiedenes#kb9963)

Don't worry,  the driver is also in english ;)